# vert.x request x-www-form-urlencoded array

Tags: http, post, request, microservices, vert.x

Good day.

I want to make a web service for processing an HTTP request. The request has:

```
Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded and body: Name=Vasya&Email=main@mail.ru&Phone=49494994&payment[sys]=none&payment[systranid]=0&payment[orderid]=1133704863&payment[products][0][name]=Мороженко&payment[products][0][quantity]=1&payment[products][0][amount]=4566&payment[products][0][price]=4566&payment[products][0][sku]=4345345345&payment[products][1][name]=Стаканчик&payment[products][1][quantity]=1&payment[products][1][amount]=100&payment[products][1][price]=100&payment[products][1][sku]=59595959&payment[amount]=4666&formid=form218781270&formname=Cart
```

I can't get payment parameters (payment{}).
I use: routingContext.request().getParam("Phone") but for payment this approach does not work.

Please help with advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Form data is plain flat key-value.

I created a little example server code based on your description:

```kotlin
suspend fun main() {
  val vertx = Vertx.vertx()
  val router = Router.router(vertx)

  router.route()
    .handler(BodyHandler.create())

  router.post("/test")
    .handler { ctx ->
      ctx.request().formAttributes().forEach {
        println("${it.key}: ${it.value}")
      }
      ctx.response().end()
    }

  vertx.createHttpServer()
    .requestHandler(router)
    .listenAwait(8080)
}
```

Running it with your body, this is the key value pairs in the map:

```
Name: Vasya
Email: main@mail.ru
Phone: 49494994
payment[sys]: none
payment[systranid]: 0
payment[orderid]: 1133704863
payment[products][0][name]: Мороженко
payment[products][0][quantity]: 1
payment[products][0][amount]: 4566
payment[products][0][price]: 4566
payment[products][0][sku]: 4345345345
payment[products][1][name]: Стаканчик
payment[products][1][quantity]: 1
payment[products][1][amount]: 100
payment[products][1][price]: 100
payment[products][1][sku]: 59595959
payment[amount]: 4666
formid: form218781270
formname: Cart
```

As you can see, there is no `Payment` key.

I suggest that you use JSON (`application/json`) for your server and client and not form-data, it will be simpler and better suited for your use-case.

If not, you can try to iterate the attributes and extract what you need from the form data.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was missing